# Spring security error with boot 1.1.5.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot

I have troubles running securing spring boot application with spring security.

Boot: 1.1.5.RELEASE

My main configuration:

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class MainConfig extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainConfig.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MainConfig.class);
    }
}
```

I tried to minimalize my security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/*").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

    }
}
```

Dependencies I've included:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

It must be some sort of missconfiguration as I succeeded with some very basic examples earlier and this problem occurs only when trying to turn old-school spring app into boot. But I would greatly appreciate a hint in which part of configuration I should look like.

The Exception is as as follows:

```
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.setAuthenticationConfiguration(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration.setGlobalAuthenticationConfigurers(java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.AuthenticationManagerConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.util.List org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.AuthenticationManagerConfiguration.dependencies; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityProperties': Could not bind properties; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'read[role]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties]: Cannot access indexed value in property referenced in indexed property path 'read[role]'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'read[role]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties]: Bean property 'read[role]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:146)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.evaluateBeanDefinitionString(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1362)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:873)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:553)
    ... 73 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.setAuthenticationConfiguration(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration.setGlobalAuthenticationConfigurers(java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.AuthenticationManagerConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.util.List org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.AuthenticationManagerConfiguration.dependencies; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityProperties': Could not bind properties; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'read[role]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties]: Cannot access indexed value in property referenced in indexed property path 'read[role]'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'read[role]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties]: Bean property 'read[role]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:470)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:459)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.AutowiredWebSecurityConfigurersIgnoreParents.getWebSecurityConfigurers(AutowiredWebSecurityConfigurersIgnoreParents.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:63)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:122)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.access$000(MethodReference.java:44)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef.getValue(MethodReference.java:258)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:84)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:103)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:143)
    ... 77 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.setAuthenticationConfiguration(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration.setGlobalAuthenticationConfigurers(java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.AuthenticationManagerConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.util.List org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.AuthenticationManagerConfiguration.dependencies; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityProperties': Could not bind properties; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'read[role]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties]: Cannot access indexed value in property referenced in indexed property path 'read[role]'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'read[role]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties]: Bean property 'read[role]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 99 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration.setGlobalAuthenticationConfigurers(java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.AuthenticationManagerConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.util.List org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.AuthenticationManagerConfiguration.dependencies; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityProperties': Could not bind properties; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'read[role]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties]: Cannot access indexed value in property referenced in indexed property path 'read[role]'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'read[role]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties]: Bean property 'read[role]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1017)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:553)
    ... 101 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration.setGlobalAuthenticationConfigurers(java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.AuthenticationManagerConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.util.List org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.AuthenticationManagerConfiguration.dependencies; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityProperties': Could not bind properties; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'read[role]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties]: Cannot access indexed value in property referenced in indexed property path 'read[role]'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'read[role]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties]: Bean property 'read[role]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 112 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.AuthenticationManagerConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.util.List org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.AuthenticationManagerConfiguration.dependencies; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityProperties': Could not bind properties; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'read[role]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties]: Cannot access indexed value in property referenced in indexed property path 'read[role]'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'read[role]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties]: Bean property 'read[role]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1017)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:912)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:553)
    ... 114 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.util.List org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.AuthenticationManagerConfiguration.dependencies; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityProperties': Could not bind properties; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'read[role]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties]: Cannot access indexed value in property referenced in indexed property path 'read[role]'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'read[role]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties]: Bean property 'read[role]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 125 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityProperties': Could not bind properties; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'read[role]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties]: Cannot access indexed value in property referenced in indexed property path 'read[role]'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'read[role]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties]: Bean property 'read[role]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:290)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:242)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1017)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:912)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    ... 127 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'read[role]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties]: Cannot access indexed value in property referenced in indexed property path 'read[role]'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'read[role]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties]: Bean property 'read[role]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:946)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:922)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:82)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.applyPropertyValues(DataBinder.java:728)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.doBind(DataBinder.java:624)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder.doBind(RelaxedDataBinder.java:93)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.bind(DataBinder.java:609)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.doBindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:275)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.bindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:225)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:287)
    ... 140 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'read[role]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties]: Bean property 'read[role]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:725)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:943)
    ... 149 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot's attempt to map your application's configuration onto the `SecurityProperties` class has failed. Specifically it's looking for a getter method for a property named `read[role]` and it can't find one.

I would guess that you've made a mistake in your `application.properties` or `application.yml` file. You want something like: `security.user.role: THE-ROLE`.

Comment: Emberassing, I adopted 3rd party configuration property file which defines `security.read.role` and didn't realize boot is trying to map it via autoconfiguration. Thanks mate